# htaccess and its usage to allow access of a url to android user using my application

Tags: java, php, android, .htaccess, arrays

**I am a newbie for this security purpose and php files**

I came to know about **htaccess** when i saw my files and databases are not secure.

I am filling `listview` in Android application from `JsonArray` parsing.This `JsonArray` is coming from **Server** when a specific **URL** is clicked on android application 
There is a **php** file on server and there i have echoed the result .
Now the problem is with the data access .When I use that url on PC from browser ,It prints all the data on the browser.
NOw how can I give access to only those user who are using my android application.
I have heard of htaccess file but dont know how to use it and write it 
Or is there any other way to secure or get rid of direct accessing from **browser**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use htaccess file but I think there better way.
.htaccess file is fine-tuning ruleset for Apache server. It can reprogram request completely. I use it normally with Static files. 
But in your case dynamic php page. Which means you can pass a security session key.
When people login to your app they create session key. **SSID** This will be alive for some limited amount of time. like 1 hour. And every request required it. 
No correct SSID means no data.